# How do I bring to front the Console Window which was spawned by C++ Service application

Tags: c++, windows, service, console-application, taskmanager

My C++ Service application (which is created by regular user, not SYSTEM, not LOCAL SERVICE) spawns Windows Console.
Via Windows' Task Manager, I do see that console but I cannot bring it to front.
Via ProcessExplorer (procexp.exe), I do see that console and I can bring it to front.

Here is the relevant code, do I miss some kind of weird setting which can satisfy Windows' Task Manager?:

```
    HANDLE hToken = NULL;
    BOOL bRet = WTSQueryUserToken(WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId(), &hToken);
    if (!bRet)
    {
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        hToken = NULL;
    }

    ZeroMemory( &pi,sizeof(pi));
    
    ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof( STARTUPINFO ) );
    si.cb = sizeof( STARTUPINFO );
    
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USECOUNTCHARS;
    si.dwXCountChars = (DWORD)pod->od.width-1;
    si.dwYCountChars = (DWORD)9999;
    si.lpTitle = (LPSTR)pod->od.title;
    
    si.wShowWindow = SW_NORMAL;
    si.lpDesktop = (LPSTR)"winsta0\\default";

    const BOOL success = CreateProcessAsUser(hToken,NULL,command,NULL,NULL,TRUE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```